# Reorder .strings file

Tags: ios, iphone, bash, ipad, localization

In my `Localizable.Strings` I try to have all pairs in alphabetical order. Is it possible to reorder them alphabetically my `Localizable.strings` file with case insensitive? Maby using genstring or special bash script?

For example i have strings:

```
"app" = "app";
"Application settings" = "Application settings";
"back" = "back";
"Back" = "Back";
"Average rating" = "Average rating";
```

I want to receive:

```
"Average rating" = "Average rating";
"app" = "app";
"Application settings" = "Application settings";
"back" = "back";
"Back" = "Back";
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use ignore case `sort`:

```
sort -f Localizable.strings
"app" = "app";
"Application settings" = "Application settings";
"Average rating" = "Average rating";
"Back" = "Back";
"back" = "back";
```

Comment: IT's okey, but sometimes I have comments for strings. and then the output is like: "YYY"="YYY", "ZZZ"="ZZZ", /*A*/, /*B*/. Anyway your answer is correct. Should I create new question and add comment clause?

Comment: Yes please create a new question and we'll try to find a solution for it.

Comment: where to write this commend "sort -f Localizable.strings"

Comment: Here you can find  my modified question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27186763/smart-reordering-strings-file

Comment: how to write the result to the same .strings file?

Comment: @SunnyShah sort - f <Localizable File path> this need to be written in Terminal