# Smart ordering Localized.strings file

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, bash, localization

In my `Localizable.Strings` I try to have all pairs in alphabetical order. Is it possible to reorder them alphabetically my `Localizable.strings`? Maby using genstring or special bash script?

**Here I have additional requirements to complete:**

### 1. Ordering should be case insensitive.

### 2. First X (e.g. five) lines should be copied, not ordered.

This requirement should be met because in Localized.strings file I have author, company name and product name as a comment on top.

### 3. Keep comments

I want to keep comments to the translated strings and keep new lines between each translation. This comments are generetad by special genstrings command for iOS developers (e.g. `find ./ -name "*.m" -print0 | xargs -0 genstrings -o en.lproj` find all `NSLocalizedString(@"Param",@"Comment")` in my code and generate pairs `/* Comment */ /r/n "Param" = "Param";` to file). Comment line before translation is optional and may have only 1 line . For example file:

```
/* This is Billy */
"Billy" = "The smartest guy in the univererse";

/* The Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy */
"42" = "the answer to life the universe and everything";

"Johny" = "Johny";

/* Optional field */
"Anny" = "Anny";
```

The output should be:

```
/* The Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy */
"42" = "the answer to life the universe and everything";

/* Optional field */
"Anny" = "Anny";

/* This is Billy */
"Billy" = "The smartest guy in the univererse";

"Johny" = "Johny";
```

This question is the more sophisticated variant ot my own question that you can find here: [Reorder .strings file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27186156/reorder-strings-file)

Comment: Can there be multiple lines of comments before an actual line?

Comment: No. Only optional one line before translation.

Comment: Are you sorting on second field as well ?

Comment: All I need is to sort by first parameter  (the key of the  translation).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Think this is what you want
In awk

```
awk 'BEGIN{RS="";FS="\n"}
{t=$NF}

match(t,/^"([^"]+)/,a){
    key[NR]=tolower(a[1])"\t"++x
    b[x]=$0
}

END {
    asort(key)
    for (i=1; i<=x; i++) {
        split(key[i],a,"\t")
        print b[a[2]] "\n"
    }
}' file
```

#### output

```
/* The Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy */
"42" = "the answer to life the universe and everything";

/* Optional field */
"Anny" = "Anny";

/* This is Billy */
"Billy" = "The smartest guy in the univererse";

"Johny" = "Johny";
```

### EDIT

To skip the first 5 lines and still print them

```
awk 'NR<6{print;next}
NR==6{RS="";FS="\n"}
{t=$NF}

match(t,/^"([^"]+)/,a){
    key[NR]=tolower(a[1])"\t"++x
    b[x]=$0
}

END {
    asort(key)
    for (i=1; i<=x; i++) {
        split(key[i],a,"\t")
        print b[a[2]] "\n"
    }
}' file
```

### EDIT 2

I think this should work on Macs

```
awk 'NR<6{print;next}
NR==6{RS="";FS="\n"}
{t=$NF}

split(t,a,"\""){
    key[NR]=tolower(a[2])"\t"++x
    b[x]=$0
}

END {
    asort(key)
    for (i=1; i<=x; i++) {
        split(key[i],a,"\t")
        print b[a[2]] "\n"
    }
}' file
```

Comment: I haven't ever use awk, but I guess I should use this command in terminal. I receive the folowing errors: `awk: syntax error at source line 5
 context is
  >>> match(t,/^"([^"]+)/, <<< 
awk: bailing out at source line 16`

Comment: @szu type `awk --version`, it may not support match

Comment: I gto awk version 20070501. I tried to google the update for Mac OS but without success...

Comment: Mac awk sucks, i'll edit it to work on mac :) I cant test this though so just tell me if something doesn't work, I'm not sure if RS="" works on macs.

Comment: Never mind :-) I cloned my project on Ubuntu and I used your scirpt. Thanks It works perfectly!

Comment: @Szu: On OSX I've installed gnu-awk using `home brew`

Comment: I put it in a file : 
``#!/usr/local/Cellar/gawk/4.1.4_1/bin/awk -f

NR<7{print;next}
NR==7{RS="";FS="\n"}
{t=$NF}

split(t,a,"\""){
    key[NR]=tolower(a[2])"\t"++x
    b[x]=$0
}

END {
    asort(key)
    for (i=1; i<=x; i++) {
        split(key[i],a,"\t")
        print b[a[2]] "\n"
    }
}``

But it's nor working, any idea why?

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way.

```
X=5; file=<file>; \
head -n $X $file && \
cat $file | sed '1,'$X'd' | \
sed 's/\([^;]\)$/\1@@@/g' | \
tr -d '\n' | \
tr ';' '\n' | \
sed 's/$/;/g' | \
awk -F "@@@" '{print $2"@@@"$1}' | \
sed 's/^@@@//g' | \
sort --ignore-case | \
awk -F "@@@" '{print $2"\n"$1"\n"}' | \
cat -s
```

Explained.

```
X=5; file=<file>; \                     # define variables
head -n $X $file && \                   # output first set of lines
cat $file | sed '1,'$X'd' | \           # process rest of the lines
sed 's/\([^;]\)$/\1@@@/g' | \           # append @@@ to lines not ending with semicolon
tr -d '\n' | \                          # remove all new lines and make a single line string
tr ';' '\n' | \                         # break single string into multiple lines at semicolons
sed 's/$/;/g' | \                       # add semicolons at the end of lines
awk -F "@@@" '{print $2"@@@"$1}' | \    # swap comment and translation
sed 's/^@@@//g' | \                     # remove extra @@@ of translations without comments
sort --ignore-case | \                  # sort
awk -F "@@@" '{print $2"\n"$1"\n"}' | \ # swap translation and comment, print with new lines
cat -s                                  # remove extra new lines
```

Comment: It's a script file? How do we use it?